# Как программно установить конкретную вариацию товара?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В WooCommerce есть товар "куртка". У него есть атрибут "цвет". Есть вариации - "черная", "белая".

Необходимо кодом подкидывать в выбор конкретную вариацию (в примере: куртка - белая).

Много чего уже перепробовал, но все работает косо или вообще не работает.

Comment: Исправь вопрос, объяснив, что значит "подкидывать в выбор". Куда, для чего, при каких условиях.

Comment: на странице редактирования вариативного товара есть настройки для выбора вариации по умолчанию